# Why is непричемыш word written with не?

Tags: этимология, правописание, composite-nouns

Why is the word *непричемыш* written with *не*, despite the fact that *ни при чем* is always written with *ни*?

Comment: As a reference, `нетакусик` is also sometimes written with `ни`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is непричемыш word written with не, despite the fact that, ни при чем always written with ни?

Apparently, it's a newly coined niche word, used (as far as I can tell) almost exclusively by people who are vocal online in their disapproval of the Russian government.

I didn't even know of its existence before you asked this question.

The person (or persons) who coined it, probably didn't know how to spell *ни при чём*, or maybe didn't care.

As with most newly coined words these days, it's spread online through writing. When people spell words they first learned by reading them, they mostly rely on visual memory (i.e. preserve the original spelling), and not on their etymology.